# Typescript error TS2504 when trying to use async iterators with Mongoose 5.11.14: must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to move away from using `@types/mongoose` after realising that `mongoose 5.11` has type information.

However I'm now encountering Typescript issues when running `tsc` on the following code:

```
for await (const document of db.myModel.find()) {
...
}
```

The error is:

```
Type 'Query<IMyDocumentType[], IMyDocumentType>' must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method that returns an async iterator.
```

Ignoring the error and running the code works fine.
Am I missing something or is there missing type information in `mongoose 5.11.14` that `@types/mongoose` had?

```
mongoose 5.11.14
node.js 12.19.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is missing type information.

[`@types/mongoose@5.10.3` defines `[Symbol.asyncIterator]` on `DocumentQuery`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@types/mongoose@5.10.3/index.d.ts#L1964), and `Query` extends `DocumentQuery`.

[`mongoose@5.11.14` does *not* define `[Symbol.asyncIterator]` on `Query`](https://unpkg.com/browse/mongoose@5.11.14/index.d.ts#L1772).

This method must be defined on any interface that is used on the right-hand side of a `for await...of` statement.

I do notice that both packages define a `QueryCursor` which extends [`stream.Readable`](https://unpkg.com/browse/@types/node@14.14.22/stream.d.ts#L22). This class *does* define a `[Symbol.asyncIterator]` method, and the [`cursor()` method of the `Query` interface](https://unpkg.com/browse/mongoose@5.11.14/index.d.ts#L1829) returns an instance of `QueryCursor`. Try to see if the following compiles and runs as you expect without using `@types/mongoose`:

```
for await (const document of db.myModel.find().cursor()) {
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm still pretty new to TS and I had no clue how to go check for myself. Will give a go at to the cursor thing and report.

Comment: Yes, doing the cursor thing does the trick, and is so much cleaner than the cursor iteration. Not ideal, but it will absolutely do until mongoose adds the definition.